# Problems running c# app on another machine

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I just finished coding a `C#` project targeting .Net v4. I'm trying to put this program onto a server running windows server 2003 and I'm running into problems.

I copied the contents of the Release directory of my project onto the server, run the .exe, and an error pops up telling me that in order to run the application I must install v4 of the .Net framework, and asks me if I would like to begin installing now.

I'm fairly certain that .Net v4 is on this machine, though. Looking in the registry I see

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\NET FRAMEWORK SETUP\NDP\
```

and under that, there is

v1.1. ...,
 v2.0. ...,
 v3.0,
 v4\Client\1033

Under Add and Remove Programs, there is an entry for the Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile. Does anybody know of any reason why this machine says I need to install .net 4 when it seems as though it is already installed?

Comment: Is your project targeting the full .Net framework, or just the client profile ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [.Net framework Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) is a "cut down" version of the .Net 4 framework with a reduced installer size.

If your application targets the *full* .Net framework 4 then you need to install this on your target machine in order for it to run.  You can see what your application targets in the property pages in Visual Studio:

[image: Target framework drop down]

Comment: thanks for the very fast response I will see if I can get away with just using the client profile.

* Edit - I will also accept this as an answer when the timer expires